# Unable to resolve host " 192.168.0.110": No address associated with hostname?

Tags: android, host

I am facing this error when I run my code to upload data on mysql database server. 
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host " 192.168.0.110": No address associated with hostname.
I have checked my Ip-address its 192.168.0.110 but its giving
 error.

here my url:

```
String url = "http:// 192.168.0.110/latTesting.php";
```

here my java code to upload lat long on mysql database local server

```
url = new URL(strings[0]);
                String lat=strings[1];
                String  lang=strings[2];
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("lat", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lat, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("lang", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lang, "UTF-8");
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: lat="+lat);
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: lang="+lang);
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: pretty sure you also need the port number

Comment: how can I use the port number

Comment: `String url = "http://192.168.0.110:PortNum/latTesting.php";`

Comment: Are you using mobile data for testing?

Comment: I am using same wifi on both devices

Comment: Try with a browser on your device.

Comment: `when I run my code to upload data on mysql database server. ` No when you try to connect to a server on your pc. And then if that succeeded to upload data to a php script. What the php script will do with the received data is irrelevant.